# How can I write the article title, author name and abstract in the center of a page?

Tags: spacing

I am using the \begin{center}...\end{center} command to center the article title, author name, and affiliation? But it gives an error. Would you please give me the right command?

Moreover, I would like to write an abstract in a smaller area rather than the main text area. For that, I am using \begin{abstract}...\end{abstract}.In that case, I want to write the title "abstract" at the beginning of the first line. Please let me know the correct way.

Thanking you,
Salim

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The style and positioning of these elements of an article are defined by the document class you are using, but you haven't identified it.  If you provide a small compilable example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` someone should be able to help.  (Edit this information into your question, please, not into a comment.)

Comment: The easier way on standard `documentclasses` is to not use the `\maketitle ` command but place them manually inside `\begin{center}\begin{minipage}{7cm}\centering  Author Name\end{minipage}...\end{center}`. This way you could avoid the need of a custom cls (document class) file that is not so easy for a begginer.